# C++ Without initialization variable

Tags: c++, logic

I have got a problem from my friends. The problem is Without initialization  of variable how to print 0 to 10?

I know method to print using for loop using initialization

```
 for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
     cout<<i;
 }
```

Here `int i = 0` was initialized. Then how can one print 0 to 10 values  without initialization  of the relevant variable? It is possible or not?

Comment: How about `cout << "012345678910"` ?

Comment: @drhirsch This is a memes "problem?" answer! lol

Comment: static int i; while(i<=10) cout << i;

Answer (score 13):

Your friends should learn to specify their problems more precisely.

```
int i; // i is not initialized
i = 0; // i is assigned
for( ;i<=10;i++)
{
  cout<<i;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Keep it simple:

```
cout << "0" << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5" << "6" << "7" << "8" << "9" << "10";
cout << "012345678910";
```

#### Run-time recursion:

```
void myPrint(int x)
{ 
    cout << x;
    if ( x < 10 )
       myPrint( x+1 );
}

myPrint(0);
```

#### Compile-time recursion:

```
template<int x> void foo()
{ 
    foo<x-1>(); 
    cout << x << '\n'; 
}

template<> void foo<0>() 
{ 
    cout << 0 << '\n'; 
}

foo<10>();
```

Comment: You template solution will output the numbers in the reverse order :-)

Answer (score 2):

The obvoiusly simplest solution can be achieved using template metaprogramming:

```
template<> void f<0>() { cout << 0; }
template<int I> void f() { f<I-1>(); cout << I; }
f<10>();
```

Or just use a recursive lambda function.

```
function<void(int)> f = [&f] (int i) { i ? f(i-1) : (void)0; cout << i; };
f(10);
```

Comment: No, a recursive lambda is even simpler, and your fellow developers will be delighted at the increased readability of the code.

Comment: That does look a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct printer {
  printer() {
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
    printer<N+1>();
  }
};

template<>
struct printer<10> {
  printer() {
    std::cout << 10 << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()  
{
  printer<0>();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int printAndAdd(int total, int next)
{
    std::cout << total;
    return total + next;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> elevenOnes(11, 1);
    std::accumulate(elevenOnes.begin(), elevenOnes.end(), 0, printAndAdd);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is nice. Until now I wasn't even aware of `std::accumulate`

Comment: This is nice, but that `elevenOnes` vector *is* being initialized - so no cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Look ma, no constants (well except for that `"%u"` string literal, but that *doesn't count!!!*)

```
#include <cstdio> /* C code. C code run. Run code, run. */

/* umad? */
static unsigned long zero, ten, i;

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
        /* setting ten to the right value... No initialization whatsoever! */
        ++ten;
        ten = ten << ten;
        ten = (ten << ten) + ten;
        /* then it's just a matter of printing out the values! */
        for (; i <= ten; ++i) {
                printf("%u", i);
        }
        /* As we all know, the Roman Empire (The unholy one, not the holy one,
           which wasn't holy, Roman, or an empire) fell since lacking any
           concept of zero, they couldn't indicate successful termination of
           their C programs. */
        return zero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution using `XOR` - if you `XOR` any value with itself, it will become zero. So the solution could be:

```
int i;
i ^= i; // this effectively sets i to zero
for (; i <= 10; i++) {
    cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about malloc, recursion, template.
or using direct access using something like 
*(long*)0x12ff7b = 1;
*(long*)0x12ff7b = *(long*)0x12ff7b +1;
as long as *(long*)0x12ff7b is in writeable memory.
thats really a open ended question

Answer (score 0):

Some other answers seem to assume that we may use parameter initialization (or assignment). I think it's cheating, but if allowed then I submit this simpler version:

```
void f(int n){
    for(; n <= 10; ++n)
         cout << n;
}

int main() {
    f(0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int I=0;
while (I!=11) {
    cout<< I; I++;
}
```

Comment: You're still using initialization, you just moved it out of the loop.

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks